# Is it possible to automatically include Toolbar in window decor?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I have just started migration to material theme using support library 23.1.
I have looked up the guides and all revolve around the following procedure..

1.Use theme without ActionBar provided by decor. I.e.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
...
</style>
```

2.Put a Toolbar widget somewhere in activity layout xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id=”@+id/myToolbar”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:minHeight=”?attr/actionBarSize”
    android:background=”?attr/colorPrimary” />
```

3.In code set this toolbar as an action bar:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blah);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

The problem is that some of my activities  use FrameLayout as a root layout and as a consequence a toolbar is placed on top of the screen and overlays existing content and therefore hides it.

One workaround would be to create vertically oriented LinearLayout and put Toolbar and FrameLayout as it's children. But, this ads complexity, another level of Views and affects performance.

My first question would be how does mechanism of setSupportActionBar(toolbar) works? Does it takes the toolbar out of its place as set in xml layout and reinserts it at the top of containing layout. Or it just leaves it there where it is?

And the main point, is it possible to use the new Toolbar as decor provided ActionBar? Leave my code unchanged and it will automagically use Toolbar instead of ActionBar? Is it possible to achieve this?

EDIT - UPDATE:
If I leave my code unchanged as if I want to leave the old ActionBar the menu in not instantiated.

EDIT - UPDATE

As far as I could gather there is no way to persuade android to create Toolbar instead of action bar. This sadly means refactoring of all activities and adding another outer enclosing Layout thereby needlessly increasing complexity.

Answer (score 1):

**First question**: How does the `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` works?

What the above statement does is make the `toolbar` act like an `ActionBar`. By default the `toolbar` does not have action bar capabilities, and to make the toolbar act like an action bar, you need this statement. The followin is the official documentation of this method.

> Set a Toolbar to act as the ActionBar for this Activity window.
>
> When set to a non-null value the getActionBar() method will return an
>   ActionBar object that can be used to control the given toolbar as if
>   it were a traditional window decor action bar. The toolbar's menu will
>   be populated with the Activity's options menu and the navigation
>   button will be wired through the standard home menu select action.

`setSupportActionBar` replaces the `decor action bar` with the `toolbar` that you are supplying as a view in the activity. This means that unlike action bar, toolbar will live as a view in your activity. It doesn't take the toolbar out of the layout and reinserts it at the top of containing layout. This means that you can have the `toolbar` anywhere you want in the screen, not necessarily at the top.

**Second Question**: Leave my code unchanged and it will automagically use Toolbar instead of ActionBar?

No, you can't do this. `Toolbar` has to be present in your `layout`, (either via xml or inflated via code). This is the whole purpose of the toolbar. With action bar you don't have this control. Toolbar allows you to modify it as much as possible and you can a different one in different activity. So how do you do it? What's the best practice?

Well, it's recommended that all activities have an accompanying fragment. So you could have a common layout for all activities (like the one below). Now, you could just inflate the fragment in the `FrameLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It seems like you did not understand the question. I know what setSupportActiionBar(toolbar) should do. I want to know the detail how it does that. As of your second recommendation. This is what I thought of myself, I just do not like the added complexity, performance and stack depth issues.

Comment: @f470071 updated my answer. Also, as for the complexity. It really doesn't add complexity. Depth wise, lesser the depth greater the performance. But this is really the only way you could have a fragment in your activity, so I wouldn't add this single level of depth into the complexity calculation. This (one step) depth is a necessary one.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly the purpose of Toolbar is to add another layer of nested views for no reason whatsoever?

Comment: No. The purpose of Toolbar is to have `complete control` of action bar, which previously we didn't have.

Answer (score 0):

of course you don't have to add the toolBar if you don't want to (but you will lost some of the cool navigation patterns the toolbar is involved at).

Just make your activity extend a theme with toolbar and you will find it there where its supposed to be.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Then in your activity you will be able to get ActionBar instance as usual:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: What will I find? New Toolabr or old ActionBar ?

Comment: You will get an ActionBar class:

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

But if you are worried about its style it is just styled like the Toolbar (same height, and MenuIcons)